# TKinter Change Label with "Next" Button

Tags: python, button, tkinter

The program is meant to review a set of sentences one at a time. I want to show one and then when the "next" button is clicked, it shows the next input. Right now it blasts through them. How do I get it to stop? I have a feeling I'm missing something small.
So here's the code:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk

root = Tk()

def iterate(number):
    return number + 1

inputs = open("inputs.txt").readlines
lines = inputs()
numlines = len(lines)
x=0
for tq in lines:
    sentence = lines[x].strip('\n')
    sen = StringVar()
    sen.set(sentence)
    x = iterate(x)
    ttk.Label(textvariable = sen).grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=99)
    ttk.Button(text = "next", command = x).grid(column=99, row=5, pady=5)   
    root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I ultimately used to solve the issue:

```
from Tkinter import * 
import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("This space intentionally left blank")
root.minsize(800,200)
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root) 
mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0)

def nextInputs(*args):     
    sen.set(inputs())

inputs = open("inputs.txt").readline
sen = StringVar()
ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=sen).grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=99)
Button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text = "next", command = nextInputs).grid(column=99, row=5, pady=5)
root.bind('<Return>', nextInputs)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

To change what is displayed in a label you can call the `configure` method, giving it any of the same arguments you give when you create it. So, you would create a single label, then call this method to modify what is displayed.

The basic logic looks like this:

```
def do_next():
    s = get_next_string_to_display()
    the_label.configure(text=s)

the_label = ttk.Label(...)
the_button = ttk.Button(..., command=do_next)
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. I'm getting a single label and I'm getting the label to change, it just doesn't wait for the button. Any advice on that?

Comment: No, you aren't getting a single label. You create a new one for each line in the file because you are creating it inside the loop. Like I wrote, you need to create a function to update the label, and call the function each time you click the button.